# Unknown class method callback that takes 0 arguments and returns type convertible to int

Tags: c++, templates, callback

I'm making a protocol interface. This protocol should server for sending ADC data from a device. Various microcontrolers have libraries that allow ADC reading but of course, they are different types.

For example, analog reading in Nucleo:

```
AnalogIn ain(A0); 
unsigned short value = ain.read_u16();
```

And Arduino:

```
int analogPin = 3;
int val = analogRead(analogPin);
```

While this methods return *different types* and are actually totally different kinds they return the same data.

My question is, whether it's possible to make a class that accepts both of these functions as callback and returns their return value as `int`.

Like this:

```
class ThisIsNotReal {
  public:
    ThisIsNotReal(<ANY TYPE THAT CAN CONVERT TO INT HERE> (*cb)() ) {
      callback = cb;
    }
    int getVal() {
       return callback();
    }

  private:
    <ANY TYPE ... (some super magical template? anyone?)> (*cb)()

}
```

Of course, my goal is to have Arduino compatible code without writing too much code. Also, I want to learn some template magic.

Comment: Have you considered `int val = static_cast<int>(ain.read_u16());`?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that `std::function` and lambda may help, something like:

```
AnalogIn ain(A0); 
std::function<int()> AdcRead = [ain](){ return ain.read_u16(); };
```

And

```
const int analogPin = 3;
std::function<int()> AdcRead = [analogPin](){ return analogRead(analogPin); };
```

Comment: @Pradhan: Now, unless specified C++98/C++03, I assume C++11/C++14.

Comment: Mind. Blown. I like this policy :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a C++11 compiler for all target devices using a callback is not necessarily going to be straightforward. This is because of the varied differences between the storage requirements and arguments required to invoke the various functions. Because if this you might consider creating a common interface for reading input from an IO port and then provide a unique implementation for each target device/platform. This would allow you to have a common method of initialization an IO related object as well as reading from an IO port.

Even if you do have a C++11 compiler for your target platforms using `std::function` or `virtual` functions may not be desirable (or even an option) if they prove to impact performance. Something like the following code might be more viable as it's simple.

```
#if defined (IS_NUCLEO)
struct InputDevice
{
    InputDevice(int port) : device(port) {}

    int read() const
    {
        return static_cast<int>(device.read_u16());
    }

    AnalogIn    device;
};
#endif

#if defined(IS_ARDUINO)
struct InputDevice
{
    InputDevice(int port) : port(port) {}

    int read() const { return analogRead(port); }

    int port;
};
#endif
```

I do suggest you tailor it to meet your exact requirements.

Answer (score 0):

`ThisIsNotReal` should store a pointer of type `ConvertFuncToIntBase* conv` and call `conv->getVal()`. You will create the appropriate instance of it by calling `makeIntConverter` in the constructor of `ThisIsNotReal`. `makeIntConverter` won't compile if the return type of the function passed to it is not convertible to `int`. While the below solution using `std::enable_if` and `std::is_convertible`, which need C++11, you can use the analogous Boost methods for C++03.

```
class ConvertFuncToIntBase
{
public:
virtual int getVal() = 0;
virtual ~ConvertFuncToIntBase(){}
};

template <typename T>
class ConvertFuncToInt : ConvertFuncToIntBase
{
public:
ConvertFuncToIntLand(T (*cb)()) : callback(cb)
{
}

int getVal()
{
 return (int)callback();
}

private:
T (*callback)();
};

template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, int>>::type>
std::unique_ptr<ConvertFuncToIntBase> makeIntConverter(T (*cb)())
{
 return std::unique_ptr<ConvertFuncToIntBase>(new ConvertFuncToInt<T>(cb));
}
```

Comment: Some *typos*: `callback` is not defined, `ConvertFuncToInt` inherits (privately) from itself, `ConvertFuncToIntLand` is not a constructor, no virtual destructor for base class, missing pointer for `makeIntConverter` (whereas `unique_ptr` would be better).